# Why do we move in the negative direction of the gradient in Gradient Descent?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent

It is said that backpropagation, with Gradient Descent, seeks to minimize a cost function using the formula:

$$ W_{new} = W_{old} - learningRate \cdot \frac{\partial E}{\partial W} $$

My question is, if the derivate indicates in which direction the function (the graph of the error with respect to the weights) is decreasing, then why subtract from an **already negative** gradient?

Why not allow the current direction of the gradient (negative lets say) to be the driving factor for updating the weights:

$$ W_{new} = W_{old} + learningRate \cdot (-gradient) $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple example where the cost function to be a parabola $y=x^2$ which is convex(ideal case) with a one global minima at $x=0$

Here your $y$ is the independent variable and $x$ is the dependent variable, analogus to the weights of model that you are trying to learn.

This is how it would look like.

[image]

Let's apply gradient descent to this particular cost function(parabola) to find it's minima.

From calculus it is clear that $dy/dx = 2*x$. So that means that the gradients are positive in the $1^{st}$ quadrant and negative in the $2^{nd}$. That means for every **positive** small step in x that we take, we move away from origin in the $1^{st}$ quadrant and move towards the origin in the $2^{nd}$ quadrant(step is still positive).

In the update rule of gradient descent the '-' negative sign basically negates the gradient and hence always moves towards the local minima.

- $1^{st}$ quadrant -> gradient is positive, but if you use this as it is you move away from origin or minima. So, the negative sign helps here.
- $2^{nd}$ quadrant -> gradient is negative, but if you use this as it is you move away from origin or minima(addition of two negative values). So, the negative sign helps here.

Here is a small python code to make things clearer-

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 200)
y = x**2

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y = x^2')
plt.plot(x, y)

# learning rate
lr = 0.1
np.random.seed(20)
x_start = np.random.normal(0, 2, 1)
dy_dx_old = 2 * x_start
dy_dx_new = 0

tolerance = 1e-2
# stop once the value has converged
while abs(dy_dx_new - dy_dx_old) > tolerance:
    dy_dx_old = dy_dx_new
    x_start = x_start - lr * dy_dx_old
    dy_dx_new = 2 * x_start
    plt.scatter(x_start, x_start**2)
    plt.pause(0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the kind answer. While I do see the point your making on this practical example, in theory it just seemed hard for me to extrapolate the idea to other functions. But i think this example suffices.

Comment: This may also help: the gradient $g=\partial f/\partial x$ accounts for the magnitude of change on $f$ given a little change on $x$. Thereby, if  we call $\delta x$ the update that we decide to use $\rightarrow$ the change on $f$ would be given by $g^T\delta x$. The value that maximizes it is if $\delta x=\alpha g$ so in order to decrease our function the maximum as possible, we use $\delta x = -\alpha g$

Answer (score 1):

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous differentiable function and $d \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $d$ is called a descent direction at position $p \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, if there is a $R > 0 $ such that $F(p+rd) < F(p)$ for all $r \in (0,R)$.

In simple terms: If we move $p$ in direction of $d$ we can reduce the value of $F$.

Now $d$ is a descent direction at $p$, if $\nabla F(p)^T rd < 0 $ since by definition of gradient $F(p+rd) - F(p) = \nabla F(p)^Trd$ and in order to reduce the function value, we need to have $\nabla F(p)^T rd < 0 $:

For $f(r):= F(p+rd)$ we have $f'(t) = \nabla F(p+rd)^T d$. By assumption, $f'(0) < 0$ holds.

Since $f'(0) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$, we conclude that $d$ must be descent direction.

Therefore, setting $d := -\nabla F(p)$, we have $\nabla F(p)^T (-\nabla F(p)) = - ||\nabla F(p)||_{2}^{2} < 0 $, if $p$ is not a stationary point.

In particular, we can choose an $p' = p + r'd$ with $F(p') < F(p)$.
This shows that using the negative gradient makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Computing the gradient gives you the direction where the function increases the most. Consider f: x -> x^2 , the gradient in x=1 is 2, if you want to minimize the function you need to go in the direction of -2, same with x=-1 as the gradient is -2.

And as gradients are usually vectors, I don't know what a positive or negative gradient would be if gradient is something like (-1, 1).

https://builtin.com/data-science/gradient-descent

Comment: Same example, easy to understand! Why do you think this might not be the right place?

Comment: the question is highly related with data-science as gradient descent/ascent is such a widely used tool, but considering this page https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I think it is more related to math stack exchange (minimization of a function) or ai stack exchange

Comment: That's really just a minor remark I could/should have put it in the end of my answer I guess

Comment: I understand...

Comment: Alright, I apologize. I'm new to the website. I'll make some further research before i post again.

Comment: No need to apologize, I might be wrong and it is always better to ask a question and be redirected if needed rather than not asking it in the first place ;)